# Scala how to extract function invocations

Tags: scala, function, abstract-syntax-tree

Given a string of Scala code I need to extract the class and name of any function invocations, for example, I want to output something like:

```
com.a.b.c.SomeClassA.someFunctionA
com.a.b.c.SomeClassA.someFunctionB
com.a.b.c.SomeClassB.anotherFunctionA
```

To do this I generate an AST for the supplied code string and inspect.  I have had some success processing Apply nodes, however, I don't see a simple rule that applies in all cases to get me the information I need, for example:

```
val val2 = val1.someFunctionA
val2.someFunctionB
```

Determining the type of val2 from the AST does not appear to be trivial as the sub-tree that produces that type can be arbitrarily complex.

Is there a simple mechanism by which I can inspect an AST to extract function names and the class for each function?

I did notice, in my debugger, that under a Select node the qualifier has a rawtpe that holds an underlyingCache, this underlyingCache seems to have exactly the type information that I need, but I haven't been able to reliably extract this data (maybe because I am delving into the implementation details of the AST?).

Is there an entirely different approach that I should take?  Any ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: I think you can find the inferred types after the typer phase, have you inspected the AST after this phase?

Comment: Btw, how are you extracting ASTs, in a compiler plugin or macros?

Comment: @pedrofurla using scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox.parse then typecheck to produce an AST

Comment: I think that's the reflection API. It has limited information in its ASTs representation. You may want to check the compiler plugin usage and may be get better luck with a plugin.

Comment: @pedrofurla thanks will give the plugin a try

Comment: Btw, you may also want to try the Scala gitter channel, people there for sure will know how to approach your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols will give you information about classes and methods.

A very brute force solution, where `tree` is the typechecked `Tree` representing `val val1 = new A(); val val2 = val1.foo; val2.bar`:

```
scala> val set = tree.collect { case method if method.symbol != null && method.symbol.isMethod => method.symbol }.toSet
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[tb.u.Symbol] = Set(constructor A, method foo, method bar)

scala> set.map(sym => s"${sym.owner.name}.${sym.name}")
res25: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(A.<init>, A.foo, B.bar)
```

Comment: Thanks, symbols have what I need.

Comment: After the `isMethod` check I used `node.symbol.asMethod.fullName` to extract exactly what we required.